# Magento Category name on product title

Tags: php, magento

I got some Magento modification,

AS default in Magento list view, on title : there is a name of product, but i need to be name of category then name of product;
there is example :

1. TOURISM OD ITALY is name of category 
   2.Romantische..... is name of product

   http://pokit.org/get/?af2504d3c88d3491acb623abd6614aa2.jpg

This link is example of what i need.

My code looks like this now:

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"<?php $prod_name = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?></a>
                <?php
                $count_str = strlen($prod_name);
                if ($count_str < 30) {
                    echo $prod_name;
                } else {
                    $offset = 0;
                    $length = 34;                     
                    echo (mb_substr($prod_name,0,$length,'utf-8')). "...";;              
                }
                ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * get categories from a product
 */
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
/**
 * looping through the array of category ids
 */
foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    ?>
        Category: <a href="<?php echo $category->getCategoryUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a><br/>
    <?php
}
?>
```

$_product->getCategoryIds() gives array of category ids which the product is associated to. We can loop through this array and load each category to get the category name and url.

In this way you can get the name of the category.

Hope this will help.